# Mod_rewrite (Smacking bots)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, bots

I am going to share before asking; my question is at the bottom.

I have been having issues with scraping and useless requests consuming my very precious bandwidth so I am doing something about it. I have the following in .htaccess.

**1. Created a useless/annoying bot list and blocked them using mod_setenvif**

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (^$|^\$|^spider$|^bot$|^agent$|^crawler$) bad_bots
<Limit GET POST PUT>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=bad_bots
</Limit>
</IfModule>
```

**Explanation:** This blocks empty user agent and those identifying themselves only as bot, spider, crawler etc…

**2. Blocked the cradle of robots.txt defying bots ‘Amazon EC2’**

```
#block ec2 ips
order allow,deny
deny from 1.2.3.4/24
allow from all
```

EC2 ranges available here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=30

**3. Created a whitelist of bots I respect and expect**

```
#allowed bots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (bot|agent|spider|crawler|extractor) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(googlebot|adsbot-google|bingbot|msnbot|psbot|gigabot|twitterbot|linkedinbot|yahoo-mmcrawler|pingdom\.com_bot) [NC]
RewriteCond %{Request_URI} !^robots.txt
RewriteRule . robots.txt [PT,L]
```

**Explanation:**  If a user agent contains bot, agent, spider, crawler, extractor etc. and is not in the whitelist and not requesting for robots.txt … serve them robots.txt (maybe they forgot to ask :-))

**4. What if they fake their user agent?**

Good, I expect them to.

```
#fake user agents
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|msnbot|adsbot-google|twitterbot|yahoo-mmcrawler|slurp|gigabot) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !(create a regex of trusted bots IP ranges.)
RewriteRule . fakebots.txt [PT,L]
```

**Example:** for Googlebots' 66.249.64.1 - 66.249.95.254 its

```
^66\.249\.(64\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))|((6[5-9]|[7-8][0-9]|9[0-4])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])))|95\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-4])))$
```

Use this Google tool to create regex: http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&safe=strict&answer=55572

**Explanation:**  If you claim to be googlebot and your IP does not match the regex, you get fakebots.txt, which reads something like:

> Your user agent and IP do not match meaning you are fake! However,
>   thanks for your IP

**5. Empty referrer issue**

If you have no referrer and your IP requests more that X requests in Y amount of time, you have to pass captcha before your next request.

I need help with this, anyone? All ideas are welcome.

Comment: don't forget `User-Agent: PHP`. I wouldn't bother blocking bad googbots. First I don't think google publishes all IP addresses. Second, if bad bods can generate the google-bot user-agent header, they could just as easily generate a normal browser agent string, making them invisible. My website requires cookies, so I check to see if a cookie is present before allowing access to images (as images are the biggest files).

Comment: @Gerben I couldn’t post the entire bad bot list here, I made it short. The user agent PHP is already blocked by mod security. Google doesn’t publish IP ranges but webmasters do, basing on what they see from their logs and whois. Known ranges are here http://chceme.info/ips/
Image leaching is not such a big deal. I use this:
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer !\.example\.com leecher=1
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:leacher} 1
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ /images/stopleeching.gif [PT,NC]